# Calculating the Value-at-Risk when changing the confidence level

Tags: value-at-risk, distribution, normal

If I have a VaR estimate at a 95% confidence interval is 10, how do I calculate the approximate level of the VaR if the confidence level was raised to 99%, assuming a one-tailed normal distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that everything is normally distributed, then you just divide by normsinv(95%) and multiply by normsinv(99%).

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if there is a non-excel function or not for this but this answer gives the correct value, thanks for your help!

Comment: The equivalent Python method is  norm.ppf() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699836